# How to automatically sync local (desktop) and web databases in UWP

Tags: azure, uwp, synchronization, cloud

I am porting WPF desktop application to UWP. Previously I used Microsoft Sync Framework for synchronization between local (SQL CE) and web databases (Azure Sql Database) but it is not supported in UWP. What should i use instead of it?
I need a Windows Store desktop app + web UI (e.g. ASP.NET) and sync between local and remote databases.
One of the solutions i've found so far - create Azure Mobile App remote backend and Windows store app but I don't understand if it is possible to add also an ASP.NET-based web app in such schema and if yes - how? I need to sync data between web and local users.

Comment: Have you looked at Zumero?

Comment: Azure has a solution called "Mobile Apps" (formerly known as Azure Mobile Services) which bundles up a Web API server to allow a similar scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i chose to use Microsoft Sync Framework Toolkit. It does not automatically sync databases, you have to write some code, but it works. Another option i was thinking about was Azure SQL Data Sync, but it is still in preview.
Thanks for the answers!